# Is is possible to "disassemble" type created at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, runtime, disassembly

I'm using .NET Reflector a lot. Now I would like to "disassemble" a type which I think is created at runtime - I would like to see code of dynamic proxy generated by Entity framework 4. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this post:
[Is it possible to save a dynamic assembly to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058340/is-it-possible-to-save-a-dynamic-assembly-to-disk)

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to disassemble method bodies.  I use it when debugging Expressions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/11/16/take-two-il-visualizer.aspx